# In python 2.7, how can I wrap a class instance method or decorate it with a try/except block?

Tags: python-2.7, wrapper, decorator, try-except, instance-methods

I have a repeating set of lengthy try/except1/except2/etc blocks in a series of class methods that only differ by the outside class method being called on an outside class instance. Below is a simplified version (there are actually 4 exceptions that I am handling and eight methods that only differ by the instance method being called):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.arg = 'foo'

    def method1(self, arg1):
        err = -1
        y = None
        try:
            x = AnOutsideClass(self.arg)     # Creates a class instance of an imported class
            y = x.outsideclassmethod1(arg1)  # Calls an instance method that returns another different class instance
        except MyException1:
            x.dosomething() # Needed to handle error
        except MyException2:
            err = 0
        finally:
            del x
        return y, err

    def method2(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        err = -1
        y = None
        try:
            x = AnOutsideClass(self.arg)
            y = x.outsideclassmethod2(arg1, arg2, arg3)  # This is the only thing changed
                                                         # A different method with different argument requirements
        except MyException1:
            x.dosomething()
        except MyException2:
            err = 0
        finally:
            del x
        return y, err

    def method3 ...
```

I have been trying various ways of condensing this code by trying to wrap the two statements in the try: portion of the code by using nested functions, decorators, etc, but seem to fail due to the fact that I am have trouble translating other examples of this due to: 1) am creating a class instance that needs to be used later in one of the except blocks and 2) am calling an instance method and 3) I need to return the result of the instance method.

Is there anyway of accomplishing this with partial from functools or descriptors or any other means? I have a clunky implementation currently with an extended if/elif block that picks the instance method based on an integer code that I use in a wrapper function, but am thinking there must be a more elegant way. I am relatively new to Python and am at a loss...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function factory (i.e., a function that returns a function).

```
def make_method(methname):
    def method(self, *args):
        err = -1
        y = None
        try:
            x = AnOutsideClass(self.arg)     # Creates a class instance of an imported class
            y = getattr(x, methname)(*args)  # Calls an instance method that returns another different class instance
        except MyException1:
            x.dosomething() # Needed to handle error
        except MyException2:
            err = 0
        finally:
            del x
        return y, err
    return method

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.arg = 'foo'
    method1 = make_method('outsideclassmethod1')
    method2 = make_method('outsideclassmethod2')
```

The `make_method` is passed the outside method name as a string.
[`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) is used (inside `method`) to get the actual method from `x` given the string `methname`.
`getattr(x, 'foo')` is equivalent to `x.foo`.

The `*` in `def method(self, *args)` tells Python that `method` can accept an arbitrary number of positional arguments.
Inside `method`, `args` is a tuple. The `*` in  `y = getattr(x, methname)(*args)` tells Python to pass the elements in `args` as individual arguments to the method returned by `getattr(x, methname)`. The `*` unpacking operator is explained in [the docs, here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), and also in [this blog](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).